# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin removes DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using Python Flask for my backend with the / route going to static/dist which is webpack's build destination. I am using React on the frontend. When I do a build in web pack it removes all nodes within the body tag. Which causes `Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element`. I have verified this is the issue by adding the div to the generated index.html. Anybody know a way to copy those nodes? I have tried adding different configurations for the HtmlWebpackPlugin. I have also tried to dynamically add a document element in my index.jsx file before calling render.  Here is my webpack config.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader',
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({title:"my app"})
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` does not generate "react" specific html. In this case, the html generated would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case, you can specify a template, where you would manually create this div that you need.

To make this work, you simply:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path_to_where_my_template_is,
  inject: 'body',
  alwaysWriteToDisk: true
});
```

Webpack will inject the required script tags to you.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, I added the filename property and a directory called templates with an html file containing the needed div, but all that did was add the templates directory and it's html file to the dist directory, while overwriting the html code with the index.html code. I also tried the inject property using 'body to see if that would inject it, but still no luck. The documentation says filename is for the name of the output index file.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I thought one thing and wrote another one... i will update.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I needed to add the template property pointing to the index.html file.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'My App',
  template: 'index.html'
})
```